# How to convert rows with list of strings to multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to have a dataframe that looks like as follows:

```
Net   greg  Lukas mark Chris  Lucy  Mike
greg    1     0    1    0      0     0
Lukas   0     0    0    0      0     1
mark    0     0    1    1      0     0
Chris   0     0    1    1      0     0
Lucy    0     0    0    0      1     0
Mike    0     1    0    0      0     0
```

where these values come from the original dataset:

```
Net           L
greg     [greg,mark]
Lukas    [Lukas]
mark     [mark,Chris]
Chris    [Chris, mark]
Lucy     [Lucy]
Mike     [Mike]
```

and valeus 1 and 0 are assigned based on `L`.
Following this answer: [Use row's values as columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63234654/use-rows-values-as-columns/63234924#63234924), I have got this: TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str'.

I think it is due to the use of numpy.dot . The format of Net and L are dtype('O').
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand your question as converting from column `L` to one-hot-encoder. You previous question seems asking for the same. I don't understand why you marked `accepted` for that question while the answer doing the opposite. You may try this way

```
df_final = df[['Net']].join(df.L.explode().str.get_dummies().max(level=0)
                                .reindex(df.Net, axis=1))

Out[52]:
     Net  greg  Lukas  mark  Chris  Lucy  Mike
0   greg     1      0     1      0     0     0
1  Lukas     0      1     0      0     0     0
2   mark     0      0     1      1     0     0
3  Chris     0      0     1      1     0     0
4   Lucy     0      0     0      0     1     0
5   Mike     0      0     0      0     0     1
```

Comment: Hi Andy, thank you for your answer. I have marked as accepted because I was using numbers (integers). However I got some difficulties trying to replicate the method with a different dataset and since the answers were good for that question, I marked the answer as accepted. Could you please explain me a bit more about the conversion from L to one-hot-encoder? Is it the same considered in neural networks theory?

Comment: One-Hot Encode uses in Machine Learning. Machine Learning models don't understand `categorical variables`. So, any `categorical variables` must be converted to sequence of `0/1` format. This process is called `One-Hot Encoding`. The result of this process is called One-Hot-Encoder object. This is dormain of `scikit-learn`. If you install and use `scikit-learn`,  you question would be answered more simple using  `MultiLabelBinarizer` of `scikit-learn`

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation and clarification of the concept, @Andy.

Answer (score 0):

You can do `dot` with `split`

```
s=df.drop('Net',1)
df['L']=s.astype(int).eq(1).dot(s.columns+',').str[:-1].str.split(',')
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert frequencies under the names into `bool`. Extract corresponding column values using `agg`.

```
df['L']=df.iloc[:,1:].astype(bool).agg(lambda s: s.index[s].values, axis=1)

     Net  greg  Lukas  mark  Chris  Lucy  Mike              L
0   greg     1      0     1      0     0     0   [greg, mark]
1  Lukas     0      0     0      0     0     1         [Mike]
2   mark     0      0     1      1     0     0  [mark, Chris]
3  Chris     0      0     1      1     0     0  [mark, Chris]
4   Lucy     0      0     0      0     1     0         [Lucy]
5   Mike     0      1     0      0     0     0        [Lukas]
```